# Send video file via mail python

Tags: python

I'm trying to send `example.mp4` file with mail in below codes. Mail send successfully. But when I download the video in related mail. Video is not working after download from mail. But normally video is working successfully.Where is my fault ?

```
  import smtplib
    from email import message, encoders
    from email.message import EmailMessage
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
    from os.path import basename
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
    
    from_addr = 'FROM_MAIL'
    to_addr = 'TO_ADDRESS'
    subject = 'I just sent this email from Python!'
    content = 'Test'
    
    
    
    # Initializing video object
    video_file = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    
    # Importing video file
    video_file.set_payload(open('example.mp4', "rb").read())
    
    # Encoding video for attaching to the email
    encoders.encode_base64(video_file)
    
    # creating EmailMessage object
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    
    # Loading message information ---------------------------------------------
    msg['From'] = "person_sending@gmail.com"
    msg['To'] = "person_receiving@gmail.com"
    msg['Subject'] = 'text for the subject line'
    msg.set_content('text that will be in the email body.')
    msg.add_attachment(video_file, filename="example.mp4")
    
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(from_addr, 'APP_PASS')
    server.send_message(msg, from_addr=from_addr, to_addrs=[to_addr])
```

Comment: Are you sure `encoders.encode_base64(video_file)` is the right choice? You open an mp4 in binary, it's already encoded.

Comment: How can I do this ? I tried without encoders.encode_base64(video_file) but not working again

Answer (score 1):

Adding this did it for me:

```
video_file.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                        'attachment; filename={}'.format("test.mp4"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).